# Most shortcut keys in Lubuntu does not work

Tags: lubuntu, shortcut-keys

I remember I can use `Alt+F2` to open the `Run` application and execute a command. But recently, this shortcut does not work any more. But some other keys like `Ctrl+Alt+T` can still open a terminal for me.

I checked my `~/.config/openbox/lubuntu-rc.xml` file, and all the key combinations are set correctly. But only a few of them works.

Comment: You say "most" but give just one example. I remember reading about there being a problem with Alt+F2 in particular. If I find a suitable link, I'll post here.

Comment: https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/lubuntu-users/2014-April/007344.html and https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lubuntu-default-settings/+bug/1313355